# Getting error when upload training data for Azure Custom Translator using API with C#

Tags: c#, azure, translation

When I run the CustomTranslatorApiSamples solution in Visual Studio to upload combofile, I get the following error but  I have successfully created workspace, project with the sample code.

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/CustomTranslatorApiSamples

[image]

Here is my code - uploading an Excel file as ComboFile. Debugging “result” returns “Response status code does not indicate success:400 (Bad Request)."

[image]

Also, can you elaborate what the structure of “Files” and “DocumentDetails” in the Request Body should be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the exception error I think your file is not a valid JSON, check the file content.

You should use [FromForm] attribute and IFormFile in your API method parameter.
See this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] FileUploadRequest request)


public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

Then you can upload the desired file in swagger.